# calling Stored Procedure String via Rest API returns empty instead of valid String

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, oracle9i

As a back-end developer, I would like to call stored procedure connecting Oracle 9i database to fetch the single output string.

In reality, the result of the output parameter as string, returns empty.

Would you please tell me what to modify the work?

Here is my rest controller:

```java
@GetMapping(value = { "/third"})
public String getVariable (){
   String  result = "" ;

   Connection conn;
   conn = getConnection() ;

   CallableStatement cstmt = null;

   try {
       String SQL = "{call pkg1234.get_pc_lookup_value_second(?,?)}";
       cstmt = conn.prepareCall (SQL);
       cstmt.setString(1, "TES");         
       cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,  oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR );
       cstmt.execute();

       String dddresult = cstmt.getString(2);
       System.out.println(" Record :"+dddresult);
       result = dddresult; 
    }
   catch (SQLException e) {
       System.out.println(" go this");
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
   return result ;
}
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```sql
PROCEDURE get_pc_lookup_value_second (
    i_lookup_code    IN       VARCHAR2,
    o_lookup_value   OUT      VARCHAR2
)
o_lookup_value := '456';
END get_pc_lookup_value_second;
```

Comment: Why are you using plain jdbc with Spring? There are ways like jdbc templates to these kind of things in spring with ease.

Comment: What kind of templates ? I use the templates and jpa but to no avail. No one answer my previous questions so I use the primitive methods

Comment: Most of the material for this question was inexplicably editing into an answer (!) which in turn required substantial editing, in order to differentiate the voice of the question author and the answer author. I assert that the material being in the answer means this question lacks a [mcve] and so can be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Please refrain from adding detail in this way in the future - it makes for a Q&A that is hopelessly confusing, and is counterproductive in terms of the aims of Stack Overflow. We're trying to curate material that is useful for a wide number of future readers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my own library for simplicity:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.buckelieg</groupId>
   <artifactId>db-fn</artifactId>
   <version>0.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And then in code:

```
try(DB db = new DB("your-connection-string")) {
    String result = db.procedure("{call pkg1234.get_pc_lookup_value_second(?,?)}", P.in("TES"), P.out(JDBCType.VARCHAR)).call(cs -> cs.getString(2)).orElse("Unknown");
}
```

See more [here](https://buckelieg.github.io/db-fn/)

You have reported the following as your code:

```
try(DB db = new DB("jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@10.8.12.6:1521:dev")) {
    String thisString = db.procedure("{call b_pc_mob_portal_pkg.get_pc_lookup_value_second(?,?)}", 
            P.in("TES" , "i_lookup_code"),
            P.out(JDBCType.LONGNVARCHAR , "o_lookup_value" )).call(cs -> cs.getString(2)).orElse("Unknown");
    System.out.println( "thisString String  :" + thisString );

}
```

You have reported that this gives:

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lbuckelieg.fn.db.P;

You have asked:

> How can I check on whether this method need to be revised.

This is because you try to combine named parameters with anonymous ones. Either remove parameter names:

```
db.procedure("{call b_pc_mob_portal_pkg.get_pc_lookup_value_second(?,?)}", P.in("TES"), P.out(JDBCTtype.VARCHAR))...
```

or add names to procedure call statement:

```
db.procedure("{call b_pc_mob_portal_pkg.get_pc_lookup_value_second(:i_lookup_code,:o_lookup_value)}", P.in("i_lookup_code", "TES"), P.out(JDBCType.VARCHAR , "o_lookup_value" ))...
```

You have also reported that you have tried this code:

```
try(DB db = new DB("jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@10.8.12.6:1521:dev")) {
        String thisString = db.procedure("{call b_pc_mob_portal_pkg.get_pc_lookup_value_second(?,?)}", 
                P.in("TES" ),
                P.out(JDBCType.VARCHAR )).call(cs -> cs.getString(2)).orElse("Unknown");
        System.out.println( "thisString String  :" + thisString );
        }
```

And you have said:

> when I do it in this way, it gives:
>
> > buckelieg.fn.db.SQLRuntimeException: [registerOutParameter not implemented]

I think the problem is in JDBC driver. Which version do you use? Can it be updated for newer one?

You have said that this is your database:

> [image]

And also that you have downloaded:

> OJDBC7.jar
>
> https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-drivers-12c-downloads.html
>
> Here is the Oracle IDE Version fetched by the Oracle SQL Developer
>
> [image]

Very interesting. I will look into this issue.

As a temporal workaround I suggest to do the following:

Rewrite procedure as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION b_pc_mob_portal_pkg.get_pc_lookup_value_second(IN param1 VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'TES') 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
    RETURN '456';
END b_pc_mob_portal_pkg.get_pc_lookup_value_second;
```

And then in code:

```
String value = db.select("SELECT b_pc_mob_portal_pkg.get_pc_lookup_value_second(?) AS output FROM DUAL", "TES").single(rs -> rs.getString("output")).orElse("Unknown");
```

> How about procedure?

Have you tried latest version (0.3.6) of library?

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.buckelieg</groupId>
  <artifactId>db-fn</artifactId>
  <version>0.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to paste my work. Please help me check to see if there are exceptions

Comment: This is because you try to combine named parameters with anonymous ones.

Comment: Mixing named parameters with numbers ?

Comment: Update java to version 8 to make original code (the one with procedure) work

Comment: Strange , the String cannot be mapped.

Comment: Could you please post a stack trace for the error above or create an issue in the github project?

Comment: This answer was in a woeful state and required substantial editing. It still requires far more editing than is worthwhile for the post. Please do not allow question authors to put their question material in answers.

Answer (score 0):

@raju,
It may help you,Using Jpa Template with Springboot annotation.

```
 Controller class
    {
    @Autowired
    B b;
    @GetMapping(value = { "/third"})
        public String    getVariable (){
        return b.getInfo();
    }
    }
    @service
    B
    {
    @Autowired 
    A a;
    public String getInfo()
    {
    return a.getoutput();
    }
    @repository 
    interface A extends JpaRepository<Mention your Entity,String>()
    {
    @procedure(name="Execute your_procedure name")
    //return type
    public String getoutput();
    }
    }
```